# java - Escape text into JavaFX code

Tags: java, escaping, code-generation, javafx

I'm making a Java program that takes some text as input,
and has to produce the equivalent **JavaFX** code (a String literal). For instance:

> The input is the following text:
>
> ```
> Hello World! This: \ is a backslash.
> And this: {} are brackets.
> ```
>
> And the resulting JavaFX code is:
>
> ```
> "Hello World! This: \\ is a backslash.\nAnd this: \{\} are brackets."
> ```

Is there any **native** way (for example, using JavaFX SDKs) to achieve this?
If not, can someone give me the complete escaped sequences list in JavaFX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [JavaFX specification](http://javafxscript.ru/langref/ch02s03.html), the only characters that you have to escape with a backslash when using double quotation marks are:

- `"`
- `{`
- `}`
- `\`

Here's a Java method that should do what you're looking for:

```
public String escapeInput(String[] input) {
    String[] characters = {"\"", "\\", "{", "}"};
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("\"");
    for (String line : input) {
        for (String test : characters) {
            line = line.replace(test, "\\" + test);
        }
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    sb.append("\"");
    return sb.toString();
}
```